# Unable to get entity framework to generate a DbUpdateConcurrencyException (Database First)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to implement the optimistic locking model for EF. I have a column with the timestamp datatype on the tables I'm trying to do this with.

I've tried adding the `Timestamp` attribute on the member by modifying the T4 script. Running my test and seeing it not working, I then tried adding the `ConcurrencyCheck` attribute on the same member in the same way (via the T4). However, in neither case does the generated SQL actually utilize that member on updates (shown below). I've also set `Concurrency Mode` to `Fixed` on the property in the EDMX designer.

I can see the timestamp column in a separate select after the update but not on the update itself. I've tried breaking on `SaveChanges()`, changing the database record and seeing the timestamp value changing after my manual update, executing the `SaveChanges()` line and it executes fine without throwing the exception. Is there something I'm missing, do I need to roll my own timestamp comparison code, or do I need to get into the world of EF interceptors to change the SQL output? Thanks.

The generated SQL: (logged via `DbContext.Database.Log`)

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Foo]
SET [FooTitle] = @0
WHERE ([FooId] = @1)
SELECT [fooversion]
FROM [dbo].[Foo]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [FooId] = @1
```

The final version of the member after T4 generation:

```
[Timestamp]
[ConcurrencyCheck]
public byte[] fooversion { get; set; }
```

What I'm trying to get EF to do:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Foo]
SET [FooTitle] = @0
WHERE ([FooId] = @1 AND [fooversion] = @2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to roll my own checking code. It's pretty efficient, though it does require two trips to the database.

I wrote an interface that attaches to a series of partial classes I already use to attach things to my entities. It defines a lookup selector that my entity base class service can use to go to fetch the particular version. No result? Return a message. If there is a result then the entity is updates as you'd expect.

The interface:

```
public interface IVersionableDbObject<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class, IValidatableObject
{
    byte[] Version { get; }
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> LookupSelector { get; }
}
```

An implementation example:

```
public partial class Foo : IVersionableDbObject<Foo>
{
    public byte[] Version { get { return fooversion; } }

    public Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> LookupSelector
    {
        get { return foo => foo.FooId == FooId && foo.fooversion == Version; }
    }
}
```

The checking code in the base service:

```
IVersionableDbObject<TEntity> versionableSource = entity as IVersionableDbObject<TEntity>;
if (versionableSource != null)
{
    bool versionExists = innerContext.Set<TEntity>().Where(versionableSource.LookupSelector).Any();

    if (!versionExists)
        return new ValidationResult(string.Format(FooResources.EntityUpdateVersionConflictError,
                    BitConverter.ToInt32(versionableSource.Version, 0)));
}
```

The validation result is just a message which is a formatter that accepts the version trying to be looked up. The returning of a `ValidationResult` is specific to my own implementation. If you use it, do as you will.

Here's the generated SQL on the `.Any()`:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Foo] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[FooId] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[fooversion] = @p__linq__1)
)) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
```

Interestingly, when the update actually happens, EF still refreshes the row version without the `Timestamp` or `ConcurrencyCheck` attributes similar to the SQL I posted in the OP.